# Which CMS do you suggest to manage the members of a club?

Tags: cms, intranet

For a client I should build kind of an Intranet to manage the members of a club.

In this member area, the client, should have the possibility to see all the activities of the members: table reservation, print a monthly report per members etc.

On the other side the members can join events (then the admin will have an updated overview for each member) and book tables.

Do you suggest me to build everything with Wordpress? Drupal? Do you know any other alternatives open source?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use WordPress, there are several reservation system plugins. A quick search and I found Restaurant Reservations -- which would cover the whole table management part. It has add-ons including customizing forms.  And it's developed in GitHub.

If you were looking for something more in the customer management area you could check out [this list](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/7-best-wordpress-crm-plugins-for-your-business/) of CRM plugins. I did take a quick look at WP-CRM and one positive review was from someone managing a club website.

If you wanted to incorporate a CRM application and get some advanced customer management features, check out [this link](http://salesmarketingstack.com/display/wiki/Types+of+CRMs+and+CRM+Comparisons) on CRM types. Several CRM's offer WordPress plugins or ways to easily link to them from a web site.

Looking at it the other way, you have few users and some unique needs that merge customer management and booking systems. If you have experience with CSS and forms you could certainly add some custom pages with the exact features you want.  You would have to include a database to store member, event and reservation data. Personally, I see this as the high maintenance option.

WordPress offers so much flexibility today that I would check out the plugins first.